# editText "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: android

I'm trying to do something when "enter" is pressed in the "textEdit". I'm using onkeylistener, but it is showing error in the textedit part. My code is

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
                        //When "Enter" or "Search" Pressed)
                        if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                                EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

                                WebView mw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
                                mw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                                mw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                mw.loadUrl("http://i.word.com/idictionary/" + editText.getText()); 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code "editText" variable is declared and initialized inside "if" clause.
The following code should work properly:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyevent) {
                        //When "Enter" or "Search" Pressed)
                        if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) { 
                                WebView mw = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
                                mw.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                                mw.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                mw.loadUrl("http://i.word.com/idictionary/" + editText.getText()); 
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it so that after the user presses enter, the keyboard automatically hides?

Comment: Try to add the following code inside "if" clause:

`InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);`